# How to create a Dynamic Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to use Bootstrap multiselect , I used the following code

html

```
<input type="text" id="addRow"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add"/>
<form id="form1">
   <div style="padding:20px">
     <select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
     </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

and script

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var val = $("#addRow").val();
        var htm = '';
        htm += '<option>' + val + '</option>';
        $('#chkveg').append(htm);
    });
    $('#chkveg').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

i am try to add each option dynamically to the bootstrap multiselect but its not working properly

Demo page here : http://jsfiddle.net/pL4hg76b/1/

But its working statically : http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/7yq7fvsq/

Answer (score 38):

You need to use **[`.multiselect('rebuild')`](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods)** method of multiselect after you use `.append()`

```
$('#chkveg').multiselect('rebuild');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL4hg76b/3/)**

---

**Full code**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var val = $("#addRow").val();
        var htm = '';
        htm += '<option>' + val + '</option>';
        $('#chkveg').append(htm);
        $('#chkveg').multiselect('rebuild');
    });
    $('#chkveg').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any way we can remove existing data in <options>

Comment: @MangeshSathe I use this:

$select.empty().append(options);
$select.multiselect('rebuild');

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
$('#chkveg').multiselect('rebuild');
```

to the end of your button click event to rebuild the multiselect.

Answer (score -2):

You can `append` your list to bootstrap `ul` and to your `select`

```
$('.multiselect-container').append(htm);
$('#chkveg').append(htm);
```

here is new Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pL4hg76b/2/

Comment: Not a good practice